# Need a good UI development tool for newbie for a complex org chart or family chart

Tags: user-interface, family-tree

I have a very complex org chart or a family chart with confusing relationships. For eg. a child can have multiple parents and each child will have multiple properties which can point to another data up in the tree(like a dotted relationship) The data set is multiple rows of data. I want to represent them in a good UI tool. which one will be easy to learn and host or make it a stand alone application. I tried looking into other questions but doenst satisfy me much.

Comment: Are you looking for a UI component to integrate into your application? What's your OS/platform/framework?

Comment: I am not a Web technology guy. But all i know is I want to host that in a publicly running webserver. So any common OS or platform should be good

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following links:

Organization chart control with multiple parents:
http://unifosys.com/support/index.php?topic=98.0

http://unifosys.com/unifochart/